# \today and internationalization

Tags: babel, languages

I am writing a LaTeX document with internationalization support as explained on [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization). Here is my minimal file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english,frenchb,spanish]{babel}

%% Required package.                                                                                                                                                   
\usepackage{ifthen}

%% TeX function that generates the language commands.                                                                                                                  
\def\localedef#1#2{
\ifthenelse{ \equal{\locale}{#1} }{
  \selectlanguage{#2}
  \expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname ##1{##1}
  }{
  \expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname ##1{}
  }
}

%% Selected language. Can be placed anywhere before the language commands.                                                                                             
\providecommand\locale{fr}

%% Language commands.                                                                                                                                                  
\localedef{en}{english}
\localedef{fr}{frenchb}
\localedef{es}{spanish}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{\en{Example of \LaTeX \ document with multi-language support}                                                                                                   
\fr{Exemple de document \LaTeX \ avec support multi-langues}                                                                                                           
\es{Ejemplo de documento con soporte multi-idioma}}
\author{\en{Author}\fr{Auteur}\es{Autor}}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\en{Hello, this document was written based on explanations available here}
\fr{Bonjour, ce document a été écrit en suivant les explications disponibles ici}
\es{Buenos dias, este documento fue elaborado sobre la base de las explicaciones disponibles aquí}
:

\url{https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I can easily switch between languages and here I chose French (`\providecommand\locale{fr}`). When I compile with `pdflatex` and visualize with `evince`, everything works fine except that the date, given by `\today`, is in Spanish:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

ps: I'm on Xubuntu 14.04 and all my packages are up-to-date.

Comment: The active document language is the last option you choose for `babel`. Since you have `\usepackage[english,frenchb,spanish]{babel}` the language is Spanish.

Comment: @cgnieder Ok, thanks. But do you have any idea how I could adapt this with what I want to do? Should I do \date{\en{June 22, 2014}\fr{22 Juin 2014}\es{22 de junion de 2014}} and change it by hand? That's a bit of a pain, right?

Comment: why don't you just change the order of the options? `\usepackage[english,spanish,frenchb]{babel}`

Comment: @cgnieder you're right, I can do that. But I'd have hoped there was a better way. Feel free to add your answer so that I can choose it.

Answer (score 8):

Rewriting your selection code a little you can make the choice dependent on the language active at the beginning of the document.  This way you just need to write, e.g.

```
\AtBeginDocument{\selectlanguage{french}}
```

to choose the French variant.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[english,french,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{\selectlanguage{french}}

\newcommand{\localedef}[2]{\csdef{#1}##1{\iflanguage{#2}{##1}{}\ignorespaces}}
\localedef{en}{english}
\localedef{fr}{french}
\localedef{es}{spanish}

\begin{document}

\title{\en{Example of \LaTeX\ document with multi-language support}
\fr{Exemple de document \LaTeX\ avec support multi-langues}
\es{Ejemplo de documento \LaTeX\ con soporte multi-idioma}}
\author{\en{Author}\fr{Auteur}\es{Autor}}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\en{Hello, this document was written based on explanations available here}
\fr{Bonjour, ce document a été écrit en suivant les explications disponibles ici}
\es{Buenos dias, este documento fue elaborado sobre la base de las explicaciones disponibles aquí}:
\begin{quote}
  \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186033/today-and-internationalization}
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

The above `\localedef` just detects whether the current language fits with your provided abbreviation and if so outputs its text, otherwise it outputs nothing.  I have added an `\ignorespaces` to the end of this command as, like in your example, the different variants often start on new lines, which potentially adds an undesirable space to the output.
I have used commands from `etoolbox` for simplicity.

Note that `frenchb` is now depricated and one should use `french` instead.

Comment: Hmm, when you do `\babeltags{en=english}`, the `\en` command gets defined and you're redefining it to something else.

Comment: @egreg Oh, I see - the tag defines the `{en}` environment which involves defining an `\en` command.  OK - I'll update to avoid the tags shorthand.